# Save Data from Django Model Formset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, formset

How do I save data from a django model formset to the database?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
    idno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    logic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choices = (
        ('1', 'Choice1'),
        ('2', 'Choice2'),
        ('3','Choice3'),
    )
    choices = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=choices,
        null=True,
        )
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.idno
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import MyModel
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm

class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['idno'].disabled = True
        self.fields['date'].disabled = True
        self.fields['entity'].disabled = True
        self.fields['logic'].disabled = True

MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel, extra=1, exclude=(), form=MyForm)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import MyModel
from .forms import MyFormSet

def index(request):
new = MyModel.objects.filter(choices__isnull=True)
modelformset = MyFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=new)
context = {'modelformset':modelformset}
if request.method == 'POST':
    if modelformset.is_valid():
        modelformset.save()
        idno = modelformset.cleaned_data['idno']
        entity = modelformset.cleaned_data['entity']
        messages.success(request, '%s for %s submitted' % (idno, entity))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
return render(request, 'selfserve/index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ modelformset.management_form }}
<table>
<tr>
  <th>idno</th>
  <th>date</th>
  <th>entity</th>
  <th>logic</th>
  <th>choices</th>
  <th>comment</th>
</tr>
{% for form in modelformset %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ form.idno }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.date }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.entity }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.logic }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.choices }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.comment }}</td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
```

Right now, it is returning a nice table of each element in the model formset with a submit button next to each one. When I fill in the enabled fields (`choices` and `comment`), I would like the form within the formset to be saved to the database. Right now, when I click one of the submit buttons, this error occurs:

```
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

I know this generally means the management form wasn't included in the template. However, I have included that piece.

I think my issue is in a combination of views.py and index.html, I'm just not sure where. Ideally, I would like the data to be saved, and the user stays on the same page so they don't have to go back and forth as they save each one. Or, it would probably work to just have one save button that they would click after they are finished making all edits.

Comment: You don't want a submit button for each row.  All rows are submitted at once.. you just submit the form the formset is in.

Comment: Thank you - I figured that might be the case. Okay - so put the button outside of the table. What changes are necessary to actually get the data submitted?

Comment: And how would I have the rows disappear where the data has been submitted? Right now I'm only pulling in data where choices is null. So is there a way to render on the same page to cause that filter to be executed again?

Comment: Hmm I see a problem, you need to provide queryset= to your formset constructor every time, not just when you are displaying the data, but also when you are posting.  The best way is to not have two lines that construct your formset but just construct it right up top, and for the first argument use `request.POST or None`

Comment: What that does, is if it's a post, POST data will be passed.. if a GET, None will be passed, which is the behavior you want.  One thing that's confusing with Django at first is that forms/formsets always need the object/queryset they are working on, whether it's a get or a post.

Comment: Apologies for being dense...so remove the second construction of the model formset, then add `request.POST or None` before `queryset=`?

Comment: your `choices=dispositionChoices` in the `models.py`, is that true?

Comment: Nope - thanks for the catch. It's fixed.

Comment: yea `modelformset = MyFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=modelObjects)` then use that modelformset whether it's a get or a post...  Also, you could simplify your logic.. you ALWAYS are going to render at the end so just take that out of the if/else blocks altogether, just.. 'if request.method == POST.. then if formset is valid, save.  Don't render there.  If not a post.. no else.. just render at the bottom.

Comment: @little_birdie, that worked as long as all existing records were updated. how should it be altered to save just one form in the formset if only one is updated? perhaps a model formset doesn't make sense here, and I should actually be using a formset and iterating through each form?

Comment: I figured it out by adding a for loop to iterate through each form in the model formset, and adding a redirect to the same page. One issue down...a few dozen to go. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't need to loop through them.. django checks to see which forms changed and only saves those.

Comment: hmm. I updated my forms.py above. with that setup, saving just one of the forms in the formset results in a redirection to the same page, but no data is saved into the database. editing/saving all of the forms in the formset works (when there is no message that requires a different setup to handle multiple forms)